# Arc length of a function/parabola, and calculating area.

Tags: integration, conic-sections, arc-length

A skate ramp is shaped like the parabola $y = x^2$, between $x = 0$ and $x = 1$, $[0,1]$ - seen from the side.

**A)** Let $L$ be the length of the graph of the function $f(x) = x^2$, and show that
$$
L = 1/2 * \int_0^2 \sqrt{1+t^2}dt
$$

**B)** The model of the skate ramp shows the length to be 2 meters, and the width to be 1 meter. The profile of the ramp follows the function $f(x) = x^2$ for $x$ in $[0,1]$. What is the area of the ramp, expressed with $L$?

Here's a picture of the model of the skate ramp:

[image]

---

Now, I'm familiar with the arc length formula, i believe.. $t^2$ here I guess is $f'(x)^2$, so $2x$? But why is the integral from 0 to 2, and not from 0 to 1? and where does the 1/2 part come from?

My first thought is that 1/2 multiplied with the integral from $0$ to $2$ is the same as just the integral from $0$ to $1$. Is that correct?

And for B) Should I then do the integral to get the area? My question is then, won't that area just be the area on the side, on not the ramp (the part u can skate on) itself?

Comment: If you were to set up the integral for $L$ yourself, what exactly would it look like?

Answer (score 2):

$L_{rmp}$ is length of the ramp
$$ L_{rmp} = \int dl$$
$$ dl = \sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2}$$
$$ L_{rmp} = \int \sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2} = \int \sqrt{1 + (d_xy)^2} dx $$
$$ y = x^2 \Rightarrow d_x y = 2x$$
$$ L_{rmp} = \int \sqrt{1 + 4 x^2} dx$$
As we knows $x \in [0, 1]$
$$ L_{rmp} = \int_0^1 \sqrt{1 + 4 x^2} dx \ \ (1)$$
$$t = 2x \Rightarrow dt = 2 dx \Rightarrow dx = \cfrac{dt}{2}$$
$$ x_0 = 0, x_1=1  \Rightarrow t_0 = 0, t_1 = 2$$
$$ L_{rmp} = \cfrac{1}{2} \int_0^2 \sqrt{1 + t^2} dt \approx 1.48$$
As width of the ramp is a const
$$S_{rmp} = width * L_{rmp}  = 2 * L_{rmp} = \int_0^2 \sqrt{1 + t^2} dt = 2.96$$

Comment: Thank you! I have a couple of questions though; x0 and x1, and t0 and t1. What are they exactly? Is x0,x1 the x-axis [0,1], and t is [0,2] because its 2 meters in length from the origin? And lets say the ramp was 10m in width and 20m in length instead, will the area then be 10(width) mulitplied by the same integral, but from 0 to 20 instead of 0 to 2?

Comment: x_0 and x_1 is a borders of integration, x_0 = 0 and x_1 = 1 because $x \in [0,1]$. I have done a replacement $t = 2x$, borders of integration changing too $t_0 = 2 * x_0 = 2 * 0 = 0 \ and \  t_1 = 2 * x_1 = 2$.  Then if $x \in [0, 10]$ we have to  find new borders. $x_0 = 0, x_1 = 10 \Rightarrow t_0 = 2 * x_0 =0 , t_1 = 2 * x_1 = 20$ in this way we have new int $1/2 \int_{0}^{20} \sqrt{1 + t^2} dt$ it means that  length will change and it is not equal (10 * old value), but it is steal correct that $S_{rmp} = 20 * L_{rmp}$   (L_{rmp} is not equal 1.48 at this time ).

Comment: $x \in [0, 1] \Leftrightarrow x \in [x_0, x_1]$

Comment: Ah, so if I understand u right, it is correct that 20 * the integral, but now done with 0 to 20, instead of the old value that was 1.48(with 0 to 2)? But why 20 * the integral(0 to 20) and not 20 * integral(0 to 10?)

Comment: Yes! $S_{new} = 20 * \cfrac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{20} \sqrt{1+ t^2} dt$

Comment: Look at formula (1) (in solution), there integral(0 to 1) change to integral(0 to 10). After replacement of variable ($t = 2 x$) you have new integral, that borders is 0 and 20.

Comment: Ok, so if I do the integral from 0 to 20, and then multiplying that by 20*1/2 I get 4010m^2. Is that right? To me that sounds like way too much, so I might've done something wrong here.

Comment: It is wrong. Let length is a function of origin length (x_1). $L_{rmp} = L_1(x) = \int_0^{x_1} \sqrt{1 + 4 x^2} dx$, after replacement (t(x) = 2x) have new function (from new variable) $L_{rmp} = L_2(t_1) = 1/2 \int_0^{t_1} \sqrt{1 + t^2} dt = L_2(t(x_1)) = 1/2 \int_0^{2  x_1} \sqrt{1 + t^2} dt$. I claim that $S(width ,x_1) = width * L{rmp} = width * L_1(x) = width *  L_2(t(x_1))$. If you calculate you will see that is not  4010m^2. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2F2+Integrate%5BSqrt%5B1%2Bt%5E2%5D%2C%7Bt%2C0%2C20%7D%5D20

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5BSqrt%5B1%2B4x%5E2%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C10%7D%5D20